# Scraping blog articles in R using rvest package

Tags: r, rvest

For a university project I want to scrape blog articles of the Instagram blog (https://about.instagram.com/blog/announcements/break-down-how-instagram-search-works). Getting the title, date and author of the articles is no problem but when I try to get the actual article text, it returns nothing. Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem?

This is my code:

```
require ("rvest")
require ("stringr")
require ("tidyverse")
library (tidyverse)
library (rvest)
library (stringr)

### set variable to save url ###
url <- 'https://about.instagram.com/blog/announcements/break-down-how-instagram-search-works'

### scrape title of blog entry ###
titles <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('h1') %>%
  html_text()

### scrape author and date into a vector ###
author_date <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes ('._8hlt') %>%
  html_nodes ('._8hlu') #%>%
  html_text()

### separate author and date from vector into single character variables ###
author <- author_date [1]  
date <- author_date [2]

### scrape article text. does not work unfortunately. any idea why? ###
text <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes ("._8ig0 _8g86") %>%
  html_nodes ("._8g86 _9g5w _8iq8 _8ipi") %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get all text in paragraphs.

```
text2 <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes (xpath="//p[.//text()]") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: The only thing that does not work yet is to include parts of the text which do not have the <p> tag. Do you have any idea how I could include other texts with tags like h1, h2, and ul as well? So far I only managed to do the same operation with other tags but then I have several list of texts snippets which are not in the original order anymore.

Comment: Yes, you have to modifiy the Xpath for doing such search including other tags in it replacing the p for other tag classes

Comment: Anyway, if doing web scrapping expect the ids for tags to be changing on every site it is wiser to search by class.